# Unknown libraries for PGI compiler

Tags: pgi, pgi-accelerator

I've installed the PGI compiler for accelerators (20.9) but the compilation of one app cannot find 3 libraries `nvhpcatm.so`, `nvcpumath.so` & `nvc.so`. I was wondering if anyone is familiar with any of these libraries or how they're supposed to be built. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late response, I missed your post.

These are the NVHPC Compiler's (aka PGI) runtime libraries.  No need to build them.

Are the libraries not being found at runtime?  Is so, then you most like just need to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the directory that contains these libraries.  If you're running a different system that does not have access to the NVHPC 20.9 compilers, you'll need to copy them to the local system from the install's "REDIST" directory.

Example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/nvhpc/Linux_x86_64/20.9/compilers/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Update the path if you've not installed the compilers in the default location.
If using "csh" instead of "bash", use "setenv" instead of export and remove the "=".
If you don't already have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set, remove the trailing ":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

If on a separate systems, copy the contents of the "/opt/nvhpc/Linux_x86_64/20.9/REDIST/compilers/lib/" directory to the local system, then use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point the loader to the location of the library's on the local system.

Comment: I figured it out a couple of days after posting. It was a matter of which library is in which subdirectory. Thanks.